# i need to compare the ratio of two columns with current week vs previous week in aws quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight, calculated-field

my source is Aws Athena trying to create reports in a Aws quick sight, have date week in dataset, from that have calculated and extracted week number, need ratio of two columns, for that also created calculated column. now need to compare the ratio of two columns of current vs previous week. both my week number, ratio are calculated field. How to compare the calculated field with week number of current vs previous week.. any help can be highly appreciated